# How do I parse JSON with multiple keys the same?

Tags: python, json

I have json that resembles this:

```
{"posts":[{"no":3919193, "p": "kekekekek"}, 
          {"no":3929342, "p": "trololol"}]}
```

I want to extract anything that has the key "no", how would I do this?

I know I can use`json.load` to parse, but I am unsure how to access each value. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "posts" is an array, so you need to loop over the children and check if each child has a key of "no".

Comment: Hint: after `json.load`, what *is* the resulting *Python object graph*? (At this point the problem has *nothing* to do with JSON.) The graph is made up of normal Python objects: lists and dicts for the containers. As such it can be walked and manipulated using standard Python operations.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was definitely going about this the wrong way. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to loop through the dicts in `obj['posts']`:

```
obj = json.load(...)
[dct for dct in obj['posts'] if 'no' in dct]
```

For example,

```
>>> import json

>>> obj = json.loads('''{"posts":[{"no":3919193, "p": "kekekekek"}, 
          {"no":3929342, "p": "trololol"}]}''')

>>> [dct for dct in obj['posts'] if 'no' in dct]
[{u'no': 3919193, u'p': u'kekekekek'}, {u'no': 3929342, u'p': u'trololol'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you use `json.load` you will have a dictionary whose only key points to a list of dictionaries:

```
data = json.loads("""{"posts":[{"no":3919193, "p": "kekekekek"}, 
      {"no":3929342, "p": "trololol"}]}""")
nos = [i for i in data['posts'] if 'no' in i]
```

Of course every list element in your example satisfies your requirement that the object have the key "no".

Comment: It does, but this is just what I was looking for. Thank you for your response!