# load duplicate keys from nested json file as dictionary of list

Tags: python, json

I have a json file in this format,

```
{
  "details": {

    "hawk_branch": {
      "tandem": {
        "value": "4210bnd72"
      }
    },
    "uclif_branch": {
      "tandem": {
        "value": "e2nc712nma89",
        "value": "23s24212",
        "value": "12338cm82",
      }
    }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I need to keep all the `value`, however when i use `json.load` to load this file i only get one `value`, which make sense since `dict` can keep only unique `keys`.

Here is the expected output,

```
{ "hawk_branch": ["4210bnd72"] }
{ "uclif_branch": ["e2nc712nma89" , "23s24212", "12338cm82"] }
```

I have read this answer, [Python json parser allow duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321677/python-json-parser-allow-duplicate-keys) to use `object_pairs_hook` like this,

```
def parse_object_pairs(pairs):
    return pairs

# f is file
json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=parse_object_pairs)
```

but it returns entire json file as `list`.

I think its possible to do it using `lambda` as `object_pairs_hook` but i can't understand how can I use it.

Can someone please guide me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom duplicate key resolver function that turns the values of the `value` keys into a list:

```
def value_resolver(pairs):
    if all(k == 'value' for k, _ in pairs):
        return [v for _, v in pairs]
    return dict(pairs)
```

so that:

```
json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=value_resolver)
```

returns:

`{'details': {'hawk_branch': {'tandem': ['4210bnd72']}, 'uclif_branch': {'tandem': ['e2nc712nma89', '23s24212', '12338cm82']}}}`

And to dump the new data structure back to the original JSON format by converting lists to dicts with duplicate `value` keys, you can use a custom `json.JSONEncoder` subclass:

```
class restore_value(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, dict):
            return '{%s}' % ', '.join(': '.join((json.encoder.py_encode_basestring(k), self.encode(v))) for k, v in o.items())
        if isinstance(o, list):
            return '{%s}' % ', '.join('"value": %s' % self.encode(v) for v in o)
        return super().encode(o)
```

so that:

```
d = {'details': {'hawk_branch': {'tandem': ['4210bnd72']}, 'uclif_branch': {'tandem': ['e2nc712nma89', '23s24212', '12338cm82']}}}
print(json.dumps(d, cls=restore_value))
```

would output:

`{"details": {"hawk_branch": {"tandem": {"value": "4210bnd72"}}, "uclif_branch": {"tandem": {"value": "e2nc712nma89", "value": "23s24212", "value": "12338cm82"}}}}`

Comment: thank you, can you please explain it a little bit?, this works but i don't know why

Comment: Glad to be of help. This works because it selectively converts the list of tuples passed in by `object_pairs_hook` to a list by testing if all of the keys (i.e. the first items of the tuples) are equal to `'value'` first, before falling back to the default behavior of converting the list of tuples to a dict using the `dict()` constructor.

Comment: Is it possible to dump it back to the file in the same format ? I added few more `value` and I need to dump it back to file with new data in same format

Comment: if works when i do `json.dumps(d, cls=restore_value)` but when i use `json.dump(d, opfile, cls=restore_value)` it still write to file as list. Do you have any idea why ?