# json encoder different results for json.dump and json.dumps

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I had a string in this format,

```
d = {'details': {'hawk_branch': {'tandem': ['4210bnd72']}, 'uclif_branch': {'tandem': ['e2nc712nma89', '23s24212', '12338cm82']}}}
```

I wanted to write it to file in this format, converting lists to dictionaries and adding word `value` as key for each value in the list,
so `{'tandem': ['4210bnd72']}` should become

```
  "tandem": {
    "value": "4210bnd72"
  }
```

Here is the expected output file,

```
{
  "details": {

    "hawk_branch": {
      "tandem": {
        "value": "4210bnd72"
      }
    },
    "uclif_branch": {
      "tandem": {
        "value": "e2nc712nma89",
        "value": "23s24212",
        "value": "12338cm82",
      }
    }
    }
}
```

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921586/load-duplicate-keys-from-nested-json-file-as-dictionary-of-list) where someone answered to use `json.JSONEncoder`,

```
class restore_value(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, dict):
            return '{%s}' % ', '.join(': '.join((json.encoder.py_encode_basestring(k), self.encode(v))) for k, v in o.items())
        if isinstance(o, list):
            return '{%s}' % ', '.join('"value": %s' % self.encode(v) for v in o)
        return super().encode(o)
```

using above encoder, If the input is,

```
d = {'details': {'hawk_branch': {'tandem': ['4210bnd72']}, 'uclif_branch': {'tandem': ['e2nc712nma89', '23s24212', '12338cm82']}}}
```

the output will become,

```
print(json.dumps(d, cls=restore_value))
{"details": {"hawk_branch": {"tandem": {"value": "4210bnd72"}}, "uclif_branch": {"tandem": {"value": "e2nc712nma89", "value": "23s24212", "value": "12338cm82"}}}}
```

This is exactly what I wanted, but now I want to write it to a file.

```
with open("a.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(d, f, cls=restore_value)
```

But it doesn't write in the same way as output by `json.dumps`.

**Expected output,**

```
{"details": {"hawk_branch": {"tandem": {"value": "4210bnd72"}}, "uclif_branch": {"tandem": {"value": "e2nc712nma89", "value": "23s24212", "value": "12338cm82"}}}}
```

**Output i am getting,**

```
{"details": {"hawk_branch": {"tandem": ["4210bnd72"]}, "uclif_branch": {"tandem": ["e2nc712nma89", "23s24212", "12338cm82"]}}}
```

Can someone please tell me why its writing to a file differently even though I am using the encoder?

**Reproducing,**

Copy and run this using python 3,

```
import json


class restore_value(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, dict):
            return '{%s}' % ', '.join(': '.join((json.encoder.py_encode_basestring(k), self.encode(v))) for k, v in o.items())
        if isinstance(o, list):
            return '{%s}' % ', '.join('"value": %s' % self.encode(v) for v in o)
        return super().encode(o)

d = {'details': {'hawk_branch': {'tandem': ['4210bnd72']}, 'uclif_branch': {'tandem': ['e2nc712nma89', '23s24212', '12338cm82']}}}
print(json.dumps(d, cls=restore_value))


with open("a.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(d, f, cls=restore_value)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is here:

If you look into the source code of `json.__init__.py` in `CPython/Lib/json` here in github: [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/json/__init__.py)

You'll find that `json.dump` actually use:

```
if (not skipkeys and ensure_ascii and
    check_circular and allow_nan and
    cls is None and indent is None and separators is None and
    default is None and not sort_keys and not kw):
    iterable = _default_encoder.iterencode(obj)
else:
    if cls is None:
        cls = JSONEncoder
    iterable = cls(skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
        check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
        separators=separators,
        default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).iterencode(obj)
# could accelerate with writelines in some versions of Python, at
# a debuggability cost
for chunk in iterable:
    fp.write(chunk)
```

Hence the function you would want to `override` should be `json.JSONEncoder.iterencode` instead of `encode`.

Comment: thank you, this works but i lose all the indent. Is there a way to preserve indentation?

Comment: What do you mean by `indent`? By default json files are not indented and should be a single line.

Comment: This worked but I had a small issue with an unknown parameter (`_one_shot`) being passed to `iterencode`.  The solution was to add `**kwargs` as a parameter to my `iterencode` def.

Answer (score 3):

`json.dumps` with `cls` will call the `encode` method on your JSON object, which will return the string representation. `json.dump`, on the other hand, will call the `default` method which you have not implemented. From the `json.dump` docs:

> To use a custom JSONEncoder subclass (e.g. one that overrides the default() method to serialize additional types), specify it with the cls kwarg; otherwise JSONEncoder is used.

Therefore, `json.dump` is using the default `default` method which doesn't affect your original object and writes that.

The simplest way to write you file the way you want it is

```
with open("a.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(d, cls=restore_value))
```

Comment: thank you. this make sense. is this possible to use `indent` as well while doing this way? i am losing all the indent

Comment: The only downside to this is that if OP's dict is very large this might not work due to how `iterencode` works as a generator and is able to divide itself into chunks to avoid memory problems.