# connecting two dictionaries and storing it into an RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, rdd

I have a dictionary `users` with 1748 elements as (showing only the first 12 elements)-

```
defaultdict(int,
            {'470520068': 1,
             '2176120173': 1,
             '145087572': 3,
             '23047147': 1,
             '526506000': 1,
             '326311693': 1,
             '851106379': 4,
             '161900469': 1,
             '3222966471': 1,
             '2562842034': 1,
             '18658617': 1,
             '73654065': 4,})
```

and another dictionary `partition` with 452743 elements as(showing first 42 elements)-

```
{'609232972': 4,
 '975151075': 4,
 '14247572': 4,
 '2987788788': 4,
 '3064695250': 2,
 '54097674': 3,
 '510333371': 0,
 '34150587': 4,
 '26170001': 0,
 '1339755391': 3,
 '419536996': 4,
 '2558131184': 2,
 '23068646': 6,
 '2781517567': 3,
 '701206260771905541': 4,
 '754263126': 4,
 '33799684': 0,
 '1625984816': 4,
 '4893416104': 3,
 '263520530': 3,
 '60625681': 4,
 '470528618': 3,
 '4512063372': 6,
 '933683112': 3,
 '402379005': 4,
 '1015823005': 2,
 '244673821': 0,
 '3279677882': 4,
 '16206240': 4,
 '3243924564': 6,
 '2438275574': 6,
 '205941266': 3,
 '330723222': 1,
 '3037002897': 0,
 '75454729': 0,
 '3033154947': 6,
 '67475302': 3,
 '922914019': 6,
 '2598199242': 6,
 '2382444216': 3,
 '1388012203': 4,
 '3950452641': 5,}
```

The keys in `users`(all unique) are all in `partition` and also are repeated with different values(and also `partition` contains some extra keys which is not of our use). What I want is a new dictionary `final` which connects the keys of `users` matching with those of `partition` with the values of `partition`, i.e. if I have **'145087572'** as a key in `users` and the same key has been repeated twice or thrice in `partition` with different values as: **{'145087572':2, '145087572':3,'145087572':7}** then I should get all these three elements in the new dictionary `final`. Also I have to store this dictionary as a key:value RDD.
Here's what I tried:

```
user_key=list(users.keys())  
final=[]
for x in user_key:
    s={x:partition.get(x) for x in partition}
    final.append(s)
```

After running this code my laptop stops to respond (the code still shows [*]) and I have to restart it. May I know that is there any problem with my code and a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: `dict` cannot hold duplicated keys. Any duplicated key will be overwritten by the last entry.

Comment: Besides the dupe-keys-problem, your code just creates a copy of hte entire dict for each user, which with those dict sizes surely results in a memory error or your computer starting to swap.

Comment: Where is your `partitions` data coming from? If it's JSON, you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29321677/1639625)

Comment: No the partition data is a pickle file

Comment: and rather storing the result into a dictionary is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: It is is a pickle file, i.e. a real serialized Python dictionary, then how can it contain duplicate keys?

Answer (score 0):

**First dictionary cannot hold duplicate keys, duplicate key's value will be ovewritten by the last value of same key.**
*Now lets analyze your code*

```
user_key=list(users.keys()) # here you get all the keys say(1,2,3)
final=[]
for x in user_key: #you are iterating over the keys so x will be 1, 2, 3
    s={x:partition.get(x) for x in partition} #This is the reason for halting

''' breaking the above line this is what it looks like.
    s = {} 
    for x in partition:
        s[x] = partition.get(x)
     isn't the outer forloop and inner forloop is using the same variable x
     so basically instead of iterating over the keys of users you are 
     iterating over the keys of partition table, 
     as x is updated inside inner foorloop(so x contains the keys of partition 
     table).
     '''
    final.append(s)
```

Now the reason for halting is (say you have 10 keys in users dictionary).
so outer forloop will iterate 10 times and for the 10 times
Inner forloop will iterate over whole partition keys and make a copy
which is causing memory error and eventually your system gets hung due to out of memory.
**I think this will work for you**
store partition data in a python defaultdict(list)

```
from collections import defaultdict
user_key = users.keys()
part_dict = defaultdict(list)
# partition = [[key1, value], [key2, value], ....] 
# store your parition data in this way (list inside list)
for index in parition:
    if index[0] not in part_dict:
        part_dict[index[0]] = index[1]
    else:
        part_dict[index[0]].append(index[1])
# part_dict = {key1:[1,2,3], key2:[1,2,3], key3:[4,5],....}
final = []
for x in user_keys:
   for values in part_dict[x]:
       final.append([x, values])
       # if you want your result of dictionary format(I don't think it's required) then you ca use
       # final.append({x:values})
       # final = [{key1: 1}, {key2: 2}, ....]
# final = [[key1, 1], [key1, 2], [key1, 3], .....]
```

*The above code is not tested, some minor changes may be required*