# How can I parse a response with multiple identical keys to json?

Tags: python

I am working with an API (which I have no control over) that returns a response with hundreds of duplicate keys:

```
{
  "user": {
    //...
  },
  "user": {
    //...
  },
  //...
}
```

Using `response.json()` will only return one object, since it will overwrite any duplicate keys. Is there any way I can take the full response from `response.text` and turn it into something that I can parse to json?

Comment: *Returns a dict with duplicate keys*? Dicts can't have duplicate keys. So in what form is this 'dict' returned?

Comment: It sounds like you've got your concepts of "dict" and "JSON" backward.

Comment: What API has this evil response?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321677/python-json-parser-allow-duplicate-keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python json parser allow duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321677/python-json-parser-allow-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer to [Python json parser allow duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321677/python-json-parser-allow-duplicate-keys), this seems to work:

```
from json import JSONDecoder

def parse_object_pairs(pairs):
    return pairs

data = """
{
  "user": {
    "val":[1,2,3]
  },
  "user": {
    "val":[1,2,3]
  }
}
"""

decoder = JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=parse_object_pairs)
obj = decoder.decode(data)
print (obj)
# [('user', [('val', [1, 2, 3])]), ('user', [('val', [1, 2, 3])])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `object_pairs_hook` argument to [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load).

```py
text = """
{
    "user": "Adam",
    "user": "Bill"
}
"""

import json

def hook(key_value_pairs):
    users = []
    for key, value in key_value_pairs:
        if key == "user":
            users.append(value)
    return {
        "users": users
    }

data = json.loads(text, object_pairs_hook=hook)
print(data)
# {'users': ['Adam', 'Bill']}
```